# apply dictionary mapping to the column of a file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file `file.txt` with several columns (tab separated), and the first column can contain indexes such as 1, 2, and 3. I want to update the first column so that 1 becomes "one", 2 becomes "two", and 3 becomes "three". I created a bash file `a.sh` containing:

```
declare -A DICO=( [1]="one" [2]="two" [3]="three" )
awk '{ $1 = ${DICO[$1]}; print }'
```

But now when I run `cat file.txt | ./a.sh` I get:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { $1 = ${DICO[$1]}; print }
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
```

I'm not able to fix the syntax. Any ideas? Also there is maybe a better way to do this with bash, but I could not think of another simple approach.

For instance, if the input is a file containing:

```
2       xxx
2       yyy
1       zzz
3       000
4       bla
```

The expected output would be:

```
two     xxx
two     yyy
one     zzz
three   000
UNKNOWN bla
```

Comment: when you write `awk '...'` the code between the quotes is awk script.. do not confuse/mix it with bash or any other shell script..

Comment: I added a small example of input file / expected output

Comment: It is possible that the first column has other numbers. In that case a flag like "UNKNOWN" would be the best. Let me update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP had now added samples so changed solution as per that now.

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("one,two,three",array,",")} {$1=$1 in array?array[$1]:"UNKONW"} 1' OFS="\t" Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{                              ##Starting BEGIN block of awk code here.
  split("one,two,three",array,",")  ##Creating an array named array whose values are string one two three with delimiter as comma.
}
{
  $1=$1 in array?array[$1]:"UNKOWN" ##Re-creating first column which will be if $1 comes in array then its value will be aray[$1] else it will be UNKOWN string.
}
1                                   ##Mentioning 1 here. awk works on method of condition then action, so making condition is TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.
' Input_file                        ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

Since you haven't shown samples so couldn't tested completely, could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk 'function check(value){gsub(value,array[value],$1)} BEGIN{split("one,two,three",array,",")} check(1) check(2) check(3); 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '
function check(value){
  gsub(value,array[value],$1)
}
BEGIN{
  split("one,two,three",array,",")
}
check(1)
check(2)
check(3);
1'  OFS="\t" Input_file
```

Tested code as follows too:

Let's say we have following Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
1213121312111122243434onetwothree wguwvrwvrwvbvrwvrvr
vkewjvrkmvr13232424
```

Then after running the code following will be the output:

```
onetwoonethreeonetwoonethreeonetwooneoneoneonetwotwotwo4three4three4onetwothree wguwvrwvrwvbvrwvrvr
vkewjvrkmvronethreetwothreetwo4two4
```

Comment: There will only be one example to replace by line (the first column of the file). I added a small example of input / output in the original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It seems to work! How can I make it support the "tab separated" columns? It seems to replace tabs by spaces.

Comment: Looks great, thank you! In case I have 100 values in my dictionary, is there a way to avoid to have to do check(x) for x in 1..100 ?

Comment: @dhokas, for that case only I added EDIT solution, check now once. Yeah you need to add their definition eg--> one is 1 two is 2 etc and etc, will add explanations too now, let me know if any queries here.

Comment: @dhokas, added explanation too now.

Answer (score 1):

Given a `dico` file containing this:

```
$ cat dico
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

You could use this awk script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){$1=a[$1]}1' dico file.txt
```

This fills the array `a` with the content of the `dico` file and replaces the first element of the `file.txt` file if this one is part of the array.

Comment: Is this going to be efficient? From what I understand the code is enumerating over the dictionary for every line in file.txt

Comment: @dhokas The lookup efficiency is the same as the other answer, but this answer has the flexibility of defining the dictionary in a separate file and not in the awk code itself.